# identify some kind of vine

Tags: species-identification, botany

I have found this plant in Trabzon, a city in Turkey. I found it near the highway. I assume it isn't planted intentionally, but maybe left after previous ornamantel plantings. It smells good I think. I am interested in it because of the nice scent. Please could you help me to find what species is this.

[image]

[image]

edit: and I forgot to add its fruits. I want to plant this vine, but if there are better varieties, I can plant them instead.

Sadly flowers lost their conditions because i collect them 2days ago. and i transported them in a plastic bag.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i can provide photos from different angles, if thoese arent clear enough

Comment: Please add the location where you found it and if you found it in the wild or in a garden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a *clematis*, probably *clematis vitalba*.

This plant is native to Europe and Turkey. It also occurs on the westcoast of the USA and Australia/New Zealand, but it is probably introduced there. [Source occurences](https://www.gbif.org/species/3033558)

Picture from Dutch wiki:
[image]

Many clematis species have a very nice smell, and both the flower and the fruit are also nice to look at. That is why clematis species are grown in garden often, with countless varieties. They differ in color (most are white, pink or purple), in flower size and in flower time (spring/summer).

Comment: this answer is great, i was planning to plant it but i see there were better varieties with more spectacular fruits. but i dont accept this answer yet. because maybe you could want to improve your answer after i edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very un-remarkable clematis, the wild type. it looks like a bush. children smoked the stalks in old times. There are much more suitable garden varieties. clematis can develop a stalk 5cm wide after enough time, they are my favourite climber along with yellow clematis, passion fruit and wisteria. clematis seeds grow very easily.